# Inter-container communication (TCP and UDP) shows gateway IP as source IP

Tags: docker, networking, communication

I have one docker host with docker version 18.09.2. When I try to use TCP communication between two containers, on the destination host, the source IP is always showing the IP of the gateway, instead of the actual source host. For instance:

Container1 (IP is 172.17.0.2):

```
# docker run -itd --name h1 --hostname h1 centos /bin/bash
7031102d30f669388b4938fa953172762ec3bfb3ab1a6422b53aa3b0857c85e8
```

Container2(IP is 172.17.0.3):

```
# docker run -itd --name h2 --hostname h2 centos /bin/bash
3598edc19987680c208d8d540d4f774e2c68c7f4689611c845ccf94f99aeb156
```

On container1, initiate a TCP connection to container2:

```
[h1 #] nc 172.17.0.3 9000
```

The tcpdump on container1 shows an expected src and dst IP:

```
[h1 #] tcpdump -nn -i any port 9000                                                                                                                                                 
18:03:26.138787 IP 172.17.0.2.43244 > 172.17.0.3.9000: Flags [S], seq 218108783, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 172963671 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:03:26.138886 IP 172.17.0.3.9000 > 172.17.0.2.43244: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 218108784, win 0, length 0
```

However, on container2, the src IP is the gateway:

```
[h2 #] tcpdump -nn -i any port 9000                                                                                                                                                  
18:03:26.138822 IP 172.17.0.1.43244 > 172.17.0.3.9000: Flags [S], seq 218108783, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 172963671 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:03:26.138872 IP 172.17.0.3.9000 > 172.17.0.1.43244: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 218108784, win 0, length 0
```

This is the default bridge network configuration:

```
# docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "d927b5b9a76fdc5ed562ae035730625cbc9edbb02f659a00ac0384214828d67b",
        "Created": "2020-08-10T01:55:54.480991622+08:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "3598edc19987680c208d8d540d4f774e2c68c7f4689611c845ccf94f99aeb156": {
                "Name": "h2",
                "EndpointID": "66e696e9fada081773ae577ae5367d7d5f4df3665a8a0e2be6318993a7b87807",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7031102d30f669388b4938fa953172762ec3bfb3ab1a6422b53aa3b0857c85e8": {
                "Name": "h1",
                "EndpointID": "52b1ab4ce9a6bc5136db13c44bc9913fe31189863d44595d172373a222786c90",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I've tried to use different images but all have the same result. Any thoughts?

### Thanks, la

Append my iptables rules:

```
[docker_host #] iptables -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
INPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  -- !10.70.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !10.70.0.0/16
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
FWDI_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
FWDI_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
FWDO_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
FWDO_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDI_public_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
FWDO_public_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
IN_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
IN_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_public (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
IN_public_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
IN_public_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

```
[docker_host #] iptables -t nat -n -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
PREROUTING_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
PREROUTING_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match src-type LOCAL
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     224.0.0.0/24
RETURN     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  udp  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
POSTROUTING_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
POSTROUTING_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
POST_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
POST_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
POST_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POST_public (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
POST_public_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
POST_public_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
POST_public_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain POST_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain POST_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POST_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain PREROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
PRE_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
PRE_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
PRE_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain PREROUTING_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain PRE_public (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
PRE_public_log  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
PRE_public_deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
PRE_public_allow  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain PRE_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain PRE_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain PRE_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: 1- which OS are you using?
2- `ip route` within the containers gives you what?

Comment: @gmolaire
docker host is RHEL7.7
the image is RHEL7.3


`[h1 #] ip route
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 

172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.2`
`[h2 #] ip route
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.3 `

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced on my end and I am not experiencing the behavior that you described. Something very interesting and weird must be happening on your side.

The `tcpdump` on `# h1`:

```
sh-4.4# tcpdump -nn -i any port 9000
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
21:07:08.516964 IP 172.17.0.2.60074 > 172.17.0.3.9000: Flags [S], seq 2385135450, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3644697290 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:07:08.517085 IP 172.17.0.3.9000 > 172.17.0.2.60074: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2385135451, win 0, length 0
```

The `tcpdump` on `# h2`:

```
sh-4.4# tcpdump -nn -i any port 9000
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
21:07:08.517033 IP 172.17.0.2.60074 > 172.17.0.3.9000: Flags [S], seq 2385135450, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3644697290 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:07:08.517062 IP 172.17.0.3.9000 > 172.17.0.2.60074: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2385135451, win 0, length 0
```

Config of the bridge network on my side(I haven't spotted any difference):

```
docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "71db10f2d5fe7b737b94313d6a2e49c3c6d90bbfab357f9c6f0a6ef33cd54cbe",
        "Created": "2020-08-08T04:46:05.307778298+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "5dc46e9d625d1a4c683fbc9f8c523eeafdd1cc7434a48cf0bebf7f4c3e091e6f": {
                "Name": "h2",
                "EndpointID": "fa4343e05938f6e9b23ed89a9c6bbdf3320665d2ec4b7a7efe5f5a3c83c9bc58",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "5f2e38bec9df6cb26018c60ea237278cdff100ecdf37ab04a1dc5a87f69b114b": {
                "Name": "h1",
                "EndpointID": "da9e723e4e1f4406828d66fde1d5958013064c93082ef9cdcb0d6374d0cadf0e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Are you experiencing the same behavior from `#h2` to `#h1`?
Can you please share in your post the output of `traceroute 172.17.0.3`, `ip route` executed from `# h1`.
Also, `/etc/docker/daemon.json` on your docker host or any *custom* change that you might have performed on that network or on your iptables...
Have you tried to restart the docker service?

Comment: the daemon.json is empty. Yes, the behavior is the same from h2 to h1. I've tried to restart docker, restart host, reinstall docker, all lead to the same result.

I found this yesterday [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293932/why-i-get-the-gateway-ip-as-source-address-in-docker-bridge-networking/63330033#63330033 which is quite similar. And I do have plenty of iptables rules. However, I'm not sure which one is the cause. I'll paste all my rules in a new post.